# Exception on Connection.Open()- error 26

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a registration page in **asp.net** web application that connect to the database. I press submit in the page and exception is thrown:

> error 26 while trying to connect SQL Server
>
> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

The error is occurring after the line

```
conn.Open();
```

So the SQL server is recognised but he can't connect
I checked the services they all up, I checked the **connection settings** in the   program and it's writing well.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);  
conn.Open();
```

Comment: What is the value of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString`?

Comment: can you show us name or value in web.confog you set   for ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"]           , or check connection string login detail in management studio

Comment: yes. the values are set automatically when i added the connection string:      <add name="RegistrationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Registration.sdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />

Answer (score -2):

try make it like this code :

```
string _Constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection _Conn = new SqlConnection(_Constr);
```